# Como puedo limitar el tamaño de un array en javascript y html?

Tags: javascript, html, array

mi problema consta en que quiero que el usuario introduzca 5 posiciones (que la longitud del array sea de 5) en un array y que no pase de 5, ejemplo ( 1, 2, 33, 5, 7) y luego imprimir en  `<h1>` cuales numeros fueron introducidos, ademas cual es el numero mayor y cual es el numero menor, pero siempre usando while, if y los vectores array.

Este es mi HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="work js/5mm.js"></script>
    <title>5 numeros maximo</title>
    <link href="rcss/5mm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="cabeza">
        <form action="">
        <p id="boton">
        <label id="engreso"for="">ingrese cuantos Numeros quiera, para ver cual es mayor</label>
        </p>
        <p id="boten">
        <input type="number" name="numero" placeholder="insertar 5 numeros maximo">
        <input type="button" value="enviar" max="5" onclick="cinco()">
        </p> 
        </form>
    </div>    

   <div id="cuerpo">

    <h1 id="yax">Cual es el numero mayor</h1>

    <h1 id="res">R//numero mayor</h1>

    <h1 id="yax">Cuales numeros introdujo</h1>

    <h1 id="nmenor">R//numero mayor</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es mi Javascript

```
function cinco(){
   var numero = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('numero')[0].value);
   var arraymym = [numero]
   var numenor =0;     
   var numayor =0;
   var x=0;   //x tiene que ser menor que array
   while(x < numero){
   var dato = parseInt(prompt('ingrese numero '+ x )); 
   if(x==0){
   numayor = dato;
   numenor = dato;
   }

   if(dato > numayor){
   numayor = dato;// va guardaddo los mayores
   }

   if(dato < numenor){
   numenor = dato;// va guardando los menores
   }
   x++ 
   }
   document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = numayor;

   document.getElementById('nmenor').innerHTML = numenor;

   }
```

y me gustaría saber si es necesario quitar en input por que el array ya estaría limitado en en 5 posiciones de longitud.

muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Los valores se reciben en el input o desde el prompt?

Comment: la longitud del array desde el input y los numeros a comprobar desde el promot

Comment: Bien gracias por las aclaraciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo realizar la siguiente condición dentro de tu función que envia una alerta al usuario de que se excedió el limite que tu estableciste.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cinco(){
   var numero = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('numero')[0].value);


    if(numero > 5){

        alert("Debes introducir un número menor o igual a 5");

        return false;
    }
    //.... // Tu código adicional 
}//Fin de la función
</script>
```

Con esto obligas al usuario a que no exceda el limite. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya tienes una solución me gustaría proponerte la siguiente con miras de hacer un tanto mas simple lo que pretendes:

- Obtenemos y asignamos a variables todas las etiquetas HTML donde planeamos mostrar:

  - Total de números del vector
  - Número mayor ingresado
  - Número menor ingresado
- En una variable extra declaramos un vector vacío que se irá llenando a medida que se ingresen valores en la caja de texto
- Podemos manejar el ingreso de valores por medio del evento **`enter`**
- Para limitar la cantidad de números a 5, verificamos la longitud del vector con una estructura condicional simple
- Si el vector aún no se llena entonces seguimos recibiendo valores a través del evento que se dispara
- Cuando el límite de valores se alcanza entonces a la variable que representa a la caja de texto:

  - La deshabilitamos
  - Colocamos su value igualado con **`""`** para que quede vacía
- Nos valemos de los métodos [**`Math.max()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) y [**`Math.min()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min) para encontrar los valores mayor y menor del vector

**PROPUESTA EN CÓDIGO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Teclea los números  
    <input id="lista" type="number" />
    <h1>El número mayor es: <span></span> </h1>
    <h2>El número menor es: <span></span> </h2>
    <h3>Total de números: <span></span> </h3>
    <script>
        let lista = document.getElementById("lista")
        let mayor = document.querySelector("h1 span")
        let menor = document.querySelector("h2 span")
        let listado = document.querySelector("h3 span")
        let concentradoNumeros = []
        
        lista.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (concentradoNumeros.length < 5) {
              concentradoNumeros.push(lista.value)
              lista.value = ""
              lista.focus()
              mayor.innerText = Math.max(...concentradoNumeros)
              menor.innerText = Math.min(...concentradoNumeros)
              listado.innerText = concentradoNumeros
            } else {
              lista.disabled = true
              lista.value = ""
            }
          }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```